# How to give input date field for registration form in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to give datepicker by following android studio tutorial.
This is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
    }
}
```

DatePickerFragment.java looks like

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
    }
}
```

When i try to run the code the following error i got in cosole ::: 
Error:(18, 20) error: no suitable method found for show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,String)
method DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentManager)
method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to FragmentTransaction)

Finally my activity_main.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.acknotech.kiran.dateexample.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pick_date"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

where i made wrong?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your layout file

```
<LinearLayout      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.geelani.datepicker.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pick_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pick date"
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
```

and add this to your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int mYear,mMonth,mDay;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_date);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);

    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
          // myCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
            String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
            textView.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }


    };

    pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // Display Selected date in textbox

                            if (year < mYear)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                            if (monthOfYear < mMonth && year == mYear)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                            if (dayOfMonth < mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
                                view.updateDate(mYear,mMonth,mDay);

                            textView.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            dpd.show();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much for you concern. Just now my work done with http://stackoverflow.com/a/39031889/5398475 this...

Comment: If it worked for you..then you can accept my answer and put a Up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as picker has its own view that would pop up on using show and adding these values make it this as default date:

```
   // On the click of registration field:
   Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance()
   new DatePickerDialog(classname.this, date, now
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), now(Calendar.MONTH),
                now(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show(); // this shows the picker
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to use DatePickerDialog:

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);// Selected Date Goes Here.

            // You Can Do Anything You Want Here

        }
    }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            , calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            , calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```